# Laravel Controller UNIT Testing Issue?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4

I am creating a Laravel 4 app and i have run into a little snag. While writing tests for my controller i noticed for some strange reason it can never seem to validate. Heres my (stripped down) controller codes.

```
<?php use Controllers\Base\PublicController;

class GuestController extends PublicController {

    /**
     * Display the report issue form.
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function getReportIssue()
    {
        $this->layout->title = Lang::get('app.report_issue');

        $this->layout->content = View::make('guest.report_issue');
    }

    public function postReportIssue()
    {
        $rules = [
            'full_name' => 'required|min:2|max:100',
            'email'     => 'required|email',
            'issue'     => 'required|min:10|max:1000',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::route('guest.report_issue')
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validator->messages());
        }

        return Redirect::route('guest.reported_issue')
            ->with('msg', 'Okay');
    }
}
```

Now he tests ive created for the two methods above are...

```
public function testHandleFailReportIssue()
{
    Input::replace([
        'full_name' => '',
        'email'     => '',
        'issue'     => '',
    ]);

    $this->call('POST', 'report-issue');

    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('guest.report_issue');

    $this->assertSessionHasErrors(['full_name', 'email', 'issue']);
}

public function testHandlePassReportIssue()
{
    Input::replace([
        'full_name' => 'John Doe',
        'email'     => 'john@localhost.dev',
        'issue'     => 'Lorem ipsum idom lola singel tudor reopmatica loesn dolor gotar.
                        Lorem ipsum idom lola singel tudor reopmatica loesn dolor gotar'
    ]);

    $this->call('POST', 'report-issue');

    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('guest.reported_issue', [], ['msg']);
}
```

The initial test passes successfully, but the second one fails. After a little investigation, it shows that the Validation was not passing, which means that the `Input::replace()` method is not doing its job, because i injected valid request values. Maybe im missing something please?

[EDIT]

I decided to do this

```
public function testHandlePassReportIssue()
{
    Input::replace([
        'full_name' => 'John Doe',
        'email'     => 'john@flashdp.com',
        'issue'     => 'Lorem ipsum idom lola singel tudor reopmatica loesn dolor gotar.
                        Lorem ipsum idom lola singel tudor reopmatica loesn dolor gotar',
    ]);

    $response = $this->route('POST', 'guest.report_issue');

    dd($this->app['session']->get('errors'));

    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('guest.reported_issue', [], ['msg']);
}
```

on the test to debug by inspecting the session and like i suspected, the Input was not getting populated, any reason this could have happened? The validation messages were returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$response = $this->route('POST', 'guest.report_issue', array(
    'full_name' => 'Foo',
    'email' => 'Man@Chu.com',
    'issue' => 'FooBar'));
```

You can pass parameters as an array.